# Ruby 'gem install' won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am behind a firewall with internet blocker installed. I have power user previlage so I was able to install from git etc. But I am facing this only when I try installing 'gem'. Here is what I get, I think it says it recieved some error instead of a gzip.

Is there any config that I need to change? or any port or anything?? does it use ftp???

Please help..

[root@max-desktop max # gem install mongrel
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [the Rubygems page for Mongrel](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel), where there is a [download](http://rubygems.org/downloads/mongrel-1.1.5.gem) link.

```
$ wget http://rubygems.org/downloads/mongrel-1.1.5.gem
$ sudo gem install mongrel-1.1.5.gem
```

As a reminder, Mongrel has runtime dependencies that need to be installed first (you can use these same steps).

Answer (score 0):

no idea, but maybe try upgrading rubygems?
    `sudo gem update --system`